# Query is very slow for table having millions of records. What is the right way to handle it

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table with name table1. It has 5 columns A, B, C, D, E.

Column A is unique and can not have null values so I made Column A as Primary.

```
create table Table1
(
  A INT PRIMARY KEY,
  B INT NOT NULL,
  C DATETIME NOT NULL,
  D VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  E DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

Table1 has more than 5 millions records and it will grow over time. Application always does a search based on Column B which can have duplicate values.

Select query is very slow whenever I use column B in where clause.

I can think of two approaches:

1. Create non clustered index on column B.
2. Use column A and B as composite primary key.

What is the right way to handle this problem.

Comment: If you will use both columns A and B as your filter on your `WHERE` condition you may create as a composite key. Otherwise if you only use the B as your where clause create the non clustered index on column B. The `primary key index is hash-based` and optimizes the performance of equality-based filter expressions (e.g. (x = 0)). Note that `if the index is a composite index, the filter expressions employed must reference` **all** `of the primary key columns to take advantage of the performance gains of the index.`

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco Thanks for the response. What happens if table has composite primary key but where clause is using only one of the column.

Comment: You are doing a table scan. Means that you are not using the index at all. You must include all columns in your composite index.

Comment: 2 points: 1) Did you try Include Actual Execution Plan and what did it tell you?  And 2) if you're using SQL Server 2016+ then there is the option to use Columnstore Indexes which lets the engine do more things in memory while also using a nonclustered index.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Zorkolot I tried both approach. Non clustered index on column B and Composite primary key with Column A and B. Execution plan shows composite key performance is better. I implemented both approach and tested execution time by setting "SET STATISTICS TIME ON". Performance is almost same.

Answer (score 0):

It really depend on the queries you are using with this table, you can do a non clustered index on column A and column B, or a clustered index (composite primary key key) on A and B. Or a nonclustered index on A and B in included column.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
ON myTable(A)  
INCLUDE(B);
```

Try every case, and establish a query plan for each query. You will see what index is the best for your table.

Comment: Is it a good practice to create composite primary key with column A and B when I know that Column A is alone can be primary key.

Comment: It can be, try it and do a query plen.